# e/azhar/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.0.4.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:160:in `load_defaults': Unknown version "7.0" (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create new app using ruby 3 and rails 7, getting this error while starting the server.

Here is my `Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.0.0"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 6.0.4.4"

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem "pg"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
# gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
# gem "rack-cors"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

gem 'devise'

gem 'cssbundling-rails'

gem 'mini_magick', '>= 4.9.5'

gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.9'

gem 'bootstrap-sass','~> 2.3.2'

# gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'sass-rails'
```

I am trying to copy my old project which is built on ruby 2 and rails 7.

Comment: Your Gemfile specifies Rails version `6.0.4.4` and will thus not run on Rails 7.

Comment: I changed but still.

Comment: Please add the entire stack trace to your question. Also add (at least) the latest file mentioned in the stack trace that is part of your rails app (rather than one of the rails gems). Always male sure to include enough information in any quesiton you ask here to answer ALL of (1) what were you trying to do  (e.g. which exact commands are you running) (2) what is your exact code currently (3) what did you intend the code to do (4) what is the exact and full error message (5) anything else required to reproduce your error with only the information you have provided in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe if you change your gemfile version by deleting your gemfile.lock and then uninstalling this version `6.0.4.4` as the error path shows us running trying to use this old version

```
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0', '>= 7.0.2.3' # Gemfile
```

```
gem uninstall rails
gem uninstall railties
```

```
# for example

gem install rails -v 7.0.2.3 
# or only
bundle
```

and make sure...

```
config.load_defaults 7.0 # application.rb

class ... < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0] # db/migrate/*.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the correct rails version is mentioned in file `\config\application.rb`

`config.load_defaults` `rails_version` you want to use